# specifying non default YARN queue in Azure Data Factory v1 activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-hdinsight

We have a ADFv1 pipeline with an HDInsightHive type activity that submits hive script to a Hadoop HDIndight cluster. Looking at the JSON for the pipeline, there doesn't seem to be any way to specify a YARN queue that the job should be submitted to.

So it's assuming that the job is always to be submitted to the default queue. I didn't find anything in ADFv1 documentation yet to specify queue name (assuming we actually create more YARN queues on the cluster using capacity scheduler).

Can someone provide sample JSON for specifying a YARN queue in an activity if it is possible at all? Also, my requirement is specifically for ADFv1, I would also like to know if this is a limitation of ADFv1, is it fixed in ADFv2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Azure Data Factory doesn't support submitting an activity to a specific queue.

Azure Data Factory activity always submitted to the default queue.

I would suggest you vote up an idea submitted by another Azure customer.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/32956186-hdinsightspark-activity-should-support-additional

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

Comment: is it possible in ADF v2?

Comment: It is not possible in ADF v2.